# How to implement chrome casting functionality in Angular?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, button

I have a button in my Angular UI and I need to add the **chrome casting function** to the button. So that I can see the chrome cast popup on button click ,select the screen and cast the web content.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, you might be better of by starting to read the Google developer documentation: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/overview